# 'String or binary data would be truncated' without any data exceeding the length

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Yesterday suddenly a report occurred that someone was not able to get some data anymore because the issue `Msg 2628, Level 16, State 1, Line 57 String or binary data would be truncated in table 'tempdb.dbo.#BC6D141E', column 'string_2'. Truncated value: '!012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678'.` appeared.

I was unable to create a repro without our tables. This is the closest as I can get to:

```sql
-- Create temporary table for results
DECLARE @results TABLE (
    string_1 nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    string_2 nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE #table (
    T_ID BIGINT NULL,
    T_STRING NVARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #table VALUES
    (NULL, '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789'),
    (NULL, '!0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789!');

WITH abc AS 
(
    SELECT
        '' AS STRING_1,
        t.T_STRING AS STRING_2
    FROM
        UT
        INNER JOIN UTT ON UTT.UT_ID = UT.UT_ID 
        INNER JOIN MV ON MV.UTT_ID = UTT.UTT_ID
        INNER JOIN OT ON OT.OT_ID = MV.OT_ID
        INNER JOIN #table AS T ON T.T_ID = OT.T_ID -- this will never get hit because T_ID of #table is NULL
)
INSERT INTO @results
SELECT STRING_1, STRING_2 FROM abc
ORDER BY LEN(STRING_2) DESC

DROP TABLE #table;
```

As you can see the join of `#table` cannot yield any results because all `T_ID` are `NULL` nevertheless I am getting the error mentioned above. The result set is empty.

That would be okay if a text with more than 100 characters would be in the result set but that is not the case because it is empty. If I remove the `INSERT INTO @results` and display the results it does not contain any text with more than 100 characters. The `ORDER BY` was only used to determine the faulty text value (with the original data).

When I use `SELECT STRING_1, LEFT(STRING_2, 100) FROM abc` it does work but it does not contain the text either that is meant to be truncated.

Therefore: What am I missing? Is it a bug of SQL Server?

Comment: Bear in mind, we have none of UTT, MV or OT. We cannot even *start* to reproduce the results you're seeing without you doing some work to create (reduced to minimal columns) versions of these tables and some sample data.

Comment: Yes, I know. Unfortunately I am not allowed to post that tables and their structures. But without these tables the issue does not occur therefore the repro is quite hard to create because when I am replacing the table with another table the issue does not occur anymore.

Comment: Then you question currently reduces down to "does SQL Server sometime report spurious error messages" to which the answer is no, not so far as I'm aware.

Comment: What does `select @@version` report? If you're still running `RTM` then there are a bunch of [cumulative updates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/latest-updates-for-microsoft-sql-server) you're missing. What are the target column types? Are they using UTF-8 collation? Inserting `nvarchar` values into UTF-8 collated `varchar` columns can lead to length expansion due to the act of UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Aside... when inserting/updating `nvarchar` columns you should get into the habit of using National character literals so to avoid dropping Unicode characters unsupported by your database's default collation, e.g.: `N'Ⓤⓝⓘⓒⓞⓓⓔ'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-- this will never get hit` is a bad assumption. It is well known and documented that SQL Server may try to evaluate parts of your query before it's obvious that the result is impossible.

A much simpler repro (from [this post](https://sqlblog.org/2020/03/19/illogical-errors-can-be-a-factor-of-the-plan) and [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=126057961bff2e8f99e01b9a6cb9ce86)):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.t1(id int NOT NULL, s varchar(5) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE dbo.t2(id int NOT NULL);
 
INSERT dbo.t1 (id, s) VALUES (1, 'l=3'), (2, 'len=5'), (3, 'l=3');
INSERT dbo.t2 (id)    VALUES (1), (3), (4), (5);
GO
 
DECLARE @t table(dest varchar(3) NOT NULL);
 
INSERT @t(dest) SELECT t1.s 
  FROM dbo.t1 
  INNER JOIN dbo.t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

Result:

> Msg 2628, Level 16, State 1
> String or binary data would be truncated in table 'tempdb.dbo.#AC65D70E', column 'dest'. Truncated value: 'len'.

While we should have only retrieved rows with values that fit in the destination column (id is 1 or 3, since those are the only two rows that match the join criteria), the error message indicates that the row where id is 2 was also returned, even though we know it couldn't possibly have been.

Here's the estimated plan:

> [image]

This shows that SQL Server expected to convert *all of the values* in `t1` before the filter eliminated the longer ones. And it's very difficult to predict or control when SQL Server will process your query in an order you don't expect - you can try with query hints that attempt to either force order or to stay away from hash joins but those can cause other, more severe problems later.

The best fix is to size the temp table to match the source (in other words, make it large enough to fit any value from the source). The [blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2020/03/19/illogical-errors-can-be-a-factor-of-the-plan) and [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=126057961bff2e8f99e01b9a6cb9ce86) explain some other ways to work around the issue, but declaring columns to be wide enough is the simplest and least intrusive.