# Arithmetic overflow depending on group by columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, arithmetic-overflow

I'm getting this error but only when grouping by specific columns:

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
```

And I can't wrap my head around why. This is the query causing it (the sum-function is the culprit):

```
SELECT  a.AtgardAvvattningId, 
        a.ObjektId,
        sum(p.SlutLopLangd - p.StartLopLangd) As TotalLangd
    FROM AtgardAvvattning a 
        INNER JOIN Objekt o ON o.ObjektId = a.ObjektId 
        INNER JOIN Position p ON p.AvvattningAtgardId = a.AtgardAvvattningId 
        INNER JOIN Vna v ON v.PositionId = p.PositionId 
    WHERE v.OID IN (...) 
    GROUP BY a.AtgardAvvattningId, a.ObjektId, o.AtgardsDatum
    ORDER BY a.ObjektId
```

p.SlutLopLangd and p.StartLopLangd are both int columns. If I convert the values to bigints before sumation it works:

```
    sum(CONVERT(bigint, p.SlutLopLangd - p.StartLopLangd)) As TotalLangd
```

Giving this result:

| AtgardAvvattningId | ObjektId | TotalLangd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DC9... | 9B2... | 25684 |
| ECD... | 9B2... | 25700 |
| 3D0... | 9B2... | 170005 |
| 959... | 9B2... | 170005 |
| BEC... | 214... | 11814 |
| C31... | 214... | 11815 |

As you can see, no sum is even near the limit for int. The wierd thing is if I include the positionId in the group by clause like this it doesn't raise an error:

```
SELECT  a.AtgardAvvattningId, 
        a.ObjektId,
        sum(p.SlutLopLangd - p.StartLopLangd) As TotalLangd
    FROM AtgardAvvattning a 
        INNER JOIN Objekt o ON o.ObjektId = a.ObjektId 
        INNER JOIN Position p ON p.AvvattningAtgardId = a.AtgardAvvattningId 
        INNER JOIN Vna v ON v.PositionId = p.PositionId 
    WHERE v.OID IN (...) 
    GROUP BY a.AtgardAvvattningId, a.ObjektId, o.AtgardsDatum, p.PositionId
    ORDER BY a.ObjektId
```

In this case it's a 1-to-1 relationship between AtgardAvvattning and Position. This query gives the exact same result as above.

Why is it raising an Arithmetic overflow in the first place when the values are so small? And why does it work in the second? What's different? I know it's probably hard to give an answer without data and table structures but any hint would be helpful.

**Update:**

When removing the group by completly with this query:

```
    SELECT  a.AtgardAvvattningId, 
            a.ObjektId,
            p.PositionId,
            v.VnaId,
            p.StartLopLangd,
            p.SlutLopLangd,
            p.SlutLopLangd - p.StartLopLangd as Subtraction
        FROM AtgardAvvattning a 
            INNER JOIN Objekt o ON o.ObjektId = a.ObjektId 
            INNER JOIN Position p ON p.AvvattningAtgardId = a.AtgardAvvattningId 
            INNER JOIN Vna v WITH (NOLOCK) ON v.PositionId = p.PositionId 
        WHERE v.OID IN (...) 
        ORDER BY a.ObjektId
```

The result is not many rows at all:

| AtgardAvvattningId | ObjektId | PositionId | VnaId | StartLopLangd | SlutLopLangd | Subtraction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DC96... | 9B2... | 473... | 1345183 | 168501 | 174922 | 6421 |
| ECD4... | 9B2... | 07E... | 1252649 | 74602 | 81027 | 6425 |
| ECD4... | 9B2... | 07E... | 1252651 | 74602 | 81027 | 6425 |
| ECD4... | 9B2... | 07E... | 1252652 | 74602 | 81027 | 6425 |
| ECD4... | 9B2... | 07E... | 1252650 | 74602 | 81027 | 6425 |
| DC96... | 9B2... | 473... | 1345180 | 168501 | 174922 | 6421 |
| DC96... | 9B2... | 473... | 1345181 | 168501 | 174922 | 6421 |
| DC96... | 9B2... | 473... | 1345182 | 168501 | 174922 | 6421 |
| 3D08... | 9BC... | F18... | 1374284 | 199000 | 233001 | 34001 |
| 3D08... | 9BC... | F18... | 1374283 | 199000 | 233001 | 34001 |
| 9590... | 9BC... | A2D... | 1374285 | 16591 | 50592 | 34001 |
| 9590... | 9BC... | A2D... | 1374286 | 16591 | 50592 | 34001 |
| 9590... | 9BC... | A2D... | 1374287 | 16591 | 50592 | 34001 |
| 9590... | 9BC... | A2D... | 1374289 | 16591 | 50592 | 34001 |
| 9590... | 9BC... | A2D... | 1374288 | 16591 | 50592 | 34001 |
| 3D08... | 9BC... | F18... | 1374281 | 199000 | 233001 | 34001 |
| 3D08... | 9BC... | F18... | 1374280 | 199000 | 233001 | 34001 |
| 3D08... | 9BC... | F18... | 1374282 | 199000 | 233001 | 34001 |
| C31B... | 214... | B20... | 1349999 | 32756 | 44571 | 11815 |
| BEC3... | 214... | F21... | 1349998 | 205022 | 216836 | 11814 |

And however you sum the rows it should be hard to reach the int overflow limit.

Comment: A `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY` is always a sign of a flaw in your query. A `GROUP BY` already causes your data to be returned in *distinct* sets, so if you are getting duplicates, it likely means your `GROUP BY` is wrong. Otherwise the `DISTINCT` is redundant and unneeded overhead.

Comment: @Larnu I have now removed the DISTINCT from the query, still the same results and not really relevant to the question.

Comment: It *is* relevant to your SQL though, @Johan . `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` should rarely (read never) mix.

Comment: Double-check that the columns in the expression are `Int`. Does the query also work if your `CONVERT` uses `Int` instead of `BigInt`? That the result returns a number well below the limits of the int data type could be hiding the issue. You could have one row whose expression return value is out of range, but when summed together they are not. Try running a `MAX(CONVERT(bigint, p.SlutLopLangd - p.StartLopLangd))`

Comment: @FlexYourData If I convert to int I still get the same error. Running a MAX returns even lower numbers than the sum (all subtractions return positive numbers).

Comment: Long and short of it is that SQL Server does not take into account possible errors happening when building a query plan. So a calculation could for example be calculated over values that are later filtered out anyway. Therefore you must code defensively and ensure that errors cannot happen even on data that would logically be filtered out. For example, you should cast values to `bigint` *before* summing them, you should null out `0` *before* using it as a divisor, you should use `TRY_CONVERT` instead of `CONVERT`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The final value doesn't actually matter. What is likely happening, is that at some point in your `SUM` you are going over the maximum value (2,147,483,647) or minimum value (-2,147,483,648) for an `int` and getting the error.

Take this example:

```sql
SELECT SUM(V.I)
FROM (VALUES(2147483646),
            (2),
            (-2006543543))V(I);
```

This will likely generate the same error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

The result of the `SUM` however, would be 140,940,105 (well below the maximum). This is because *if* `2147483646` and `2` are summed first, then you get `2147483648`, which is larger than the maximum value of an `int`. If you `CAST`/`CONVERT` the value first, you don't get the error:

```sql
SELECT SUM(CONVERT(bigint,V.I))
FROM (VALUES(2147483646),
            (2),
            (-2006543543))V(I);
```

Comment: Yea, that's what I suspected. But what I dont understand is why does it calculate differently when adding positionId to the group by when there's a 1-to-1 relationship. It should be the exact same numbers to sum

Comment: But not in the same groups, @Johan . *If*, for example, the value `2` in the above was part of a different group, then you wouldn't get the error, despite the same numbers are being `SUM`ed; they're just in different "boxes".

Comment: @Johan any change in the query text can lead to a different plan (and potentially different estimates for which and how many rows will flow into and out of any operator, which operators are used, where implicit conversions may happen, which calculations are performed before or after any filtering, etc). [Similar question yesterday, about string lengths vs. numeric range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70770249/61305).

Comment: Yea, this has to be the explanation. But I still don't understand how it manages to reach the overflow limit with so few rows and so low numbers (I updated the question with the results without the group by). However the rows flow I don't see how it's possiple, but clearly it is somehow.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't replicate the error, @Johan . [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=21eadf53eec4a8965041d4d055ff0321)

Comment: @Larnu The source tables are a bit more complicated and has a lot more data in them, I just posted the output of the filtered data, which I thought was what was summed in the end. But Charliefaces explanation in a comment above seems reasonable, that the calculations are done before all the filtering is. When I look at the execution plan that seems to be the case ("compute scalar" is done in the middle before two more index seeks are done).